# Gráfico de tendências no ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Como reproduzir o gráfico abaixo usando ggplot2?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Dados e código do ggplot2 que estou tentando

```
ano<-c("2009", "2011", "2013","2014","2016","2017","2018","2019")
mean.est<-c(0.975, 1.204, 1.504, 1.741, 1.77,2.166,2.378,2.564)
lower<-c(0.041, 0.771, 1.114, 1.374, 1.419,1.804,1.993, 2.12)
upper<-c(1.876, 1.669, 1.867, 2.081, 2.162, 2.499,2.745, 3.021)
mean.obs<-c(2.659, 1.155, 1.56, 1.848, 1.56,2.253,2.407,2.541)
graf<-data.frame(ano,mean.est, lower, upper, mean.obs)

ggplot(graf,aes(x=ano, y=mean.est))+
    geom_pointrange(fill="black", size= .4, ymin=graf$lower, ymax=graf$upper)+ 
    ylim(0, 3)+
    ylab("Número de abates (log)")+
    xlab("Ano")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Esse tipo de problema geralmente tem a ver com a remodelagem dos dados. O formato deve ser longo e os dados em formato largo. Veja [est post do SO em Inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185252/reshaping-data-frame-from-wide-to-long-format) sobre como remodelar os dados do formato largo para o formato longo.

Repare ainda que para colocar a legenda dentro do gráfico, as coordenadas em

```
legend.position = c(0.5, 0.1)
```

estão na escala `[0, 1]` para cada eixo. O valor `0.5` significa a meio do eixo e o valor `0.1` a um décimo do início do eixo.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

Anos <- seq(min(as.integer(graf$ano)), max(as.integer(graf$ano)), by = 2)

graf %>%
  mutate(ano = as.integer(ano)) %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(
    cols = starts_with('mean'),
    names_to = 'group',
    values_to = 'mean'
  ) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = ano, y = mean)) +
  geom_line(aes(color = group)) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = lower, ymax = upper), alpha = 0.2, show.legend = FALSE) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c(mean.est = 'blue', mean.obs = 'black')) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = Anos, labels = Anos) +
  ylab("Número de abates (log)") +
  xlab("Ano") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(legend.position = c(0.5, 0.1),
        legend.title = element_blank(),
        legend.direction = 'horizontal',
        strip.text.x = element_blank(),
        strip.background = element_rect(colour = "white", fill = "white")
  )
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]